# Changing ASP.NET Identity service to use WS-Federation

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, single-sign-on, ws-federation

I am working on a new ASP.NET Core Blazor application that I am basing on the [BlazorHero](https://github.com/blazorhero/CleanArchitecture) clean architecture template.
The major modification that I need to make is the switch from its ASP.NET Core Identity based system to relying on WS-Federation SSO authentication.

My initial goal is to get the app to stop using the login screen.  (Which is caused by the
[App.razor](https://github.com/blazorhero/CleanArchitecture/blob/master/src/Client/App.razor) in the Blazor Client sending unauthorized users to login) **What do I need to modify for the app to go to the home page rather than the login screen?**

My second goal is to get the user service to return the current user information from our Ws-Federation server.  I can write the code that will populate the current user from Ws-Federation.  **How/where do I tell the Identity service what I want it to return for the current user?**

My assumption is that I will need to re-write (at minimum) the [IdentityService.cs](https://github.com/blazorhero/CleanArchitecture/blob/master/src/Infrastructure/Services/Identity/IdentityService.cs), the [UserService.cs](https://github.com/blazorhero/CleanArchitecture/blob/master/src/Infrastructure/Services/Identity/UserService.cs) and the [RoleService.cs](https://github.com/blazorhero/CleanArchitecture/blob/master/src/Infrastructure/Services/Identity/RoleService.cs) files.

Comment: This turns out to be a pretty significant endeavor that is requiring me to go through a LOT of documentation in detail.  I do intend to post the answer when I solve this, but it might be several days.

Comment: did you find a solution for your problem?